# Increasing LuaLaTeX compiling speed having 2525 chess diagrams

Tags: luatex, chess, chessboard

I want to create a book having 2525 chess position. I have already defined \tacticboard command that should print diagrams. However, due to the size, the PDF generation with LuaLaTeX goes too long (for example, no PDF was reproduced after 4 hours). How can the execution and the \tacticboard command be improved?

I provide the code with necessary parts below:

```
\documentclass[paper=8.27in:11.69in,DIV=calc,fontsize=12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[includehead, includefoot, inner=0.65in, outer=0.4in, top=0.65in, bottom=0.65in]{geometry}
%\documentclass[headings=openany,paper=165mm:240mm,DIV=calc]{scrbook}
%\usepackage[includehead, includefoot, left=20mm, right=20mm, top=17.5mm, bottom=17.5mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\usepackage{imakeidx}

\titleformat{name=\section, numberless}[display]
  {\LARGE\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\centering{\large}}
\titleformat{\part}[display]
  {\Huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\centering{\thepart}}
\titleformat{name=\part, numberless}[display]
  {\Huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\centering{\Huge}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\Huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\centering{\thechapter . }}
\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}[display]
  {\Huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\centering{\Large}}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{
 \markboth{#1}{}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\fancyfoot[LE, RO]{\thepage}

\assignpagestyle{\part}{empty}

\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{texmate}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{55}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{55}

\newcounter{diagrams}

\newcommand\printdiagrams{\footnotesize\refstepcounter{diagrams}\thediagrams}

\setchessboard{labelfontsize=0.5em, showmover=true, moverstyle=triangle, boardfontsize=14pt}
\newcommand\tacticboard[2][]{%
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
            \vfill\strut\scriptsize\vspace{-0.5em}\hspace{2.3em} \printdiagrams \hfill  #1\hspace{1.9em} \vspace{-1em}
            \par\centering\chessboard[#2]\vfill\vspace{2.1em}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\bfseries\rmfamily\Huge\vspace{0.5em}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\rmfamily\Large\vspace{0.25em}}
\renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\bfseries\rmfamily\Huge}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\rmfamily\Large}
\renewcommand\thepart{\Roman{part}. }
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hspace*{\fill}\rmfamily\bfseries\huge Contents\hspace*{\fill}}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}


\part{Positions}
\fancyhead[C]{I. Positions}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.2pt}
\tacticboard[L-0]{setfen=8/8/8/8/8/1K4Q1/7p/6k1 b - - 0 1, moverlift=-1.9ex, movershift=-8.6ex}
\tacticboard[L-0]{setfen=8/8/8/6K1/8/6Q1/5p2/6k1 b - - 0 1, moverlift=-1.9ex, movershift=-8.6ex}
...
\tacticboard[L-0]{setfen=8/3k1qP1/7K/7P/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1, moverlift=16.6ex, movershift=-8.6ex}
\tacticboard[L-0]{setfen=3q4/1P6/K1k5/P7/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1, moverlift=16.6ex, movershift=-8.6ex}

\end{document}
```

With best regards,

Comment: `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{55}` you really have sub sub sub ...  sub sections  55 levels deep?

Comment: your code mostly just consists of section commands that produce warnings `Class scrbook Warning: Usage of package `titlesec' together
(scrbook)              with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended`  but don't really seem related to the speed. Please give some instructions on how to make an example that takes a longer time than expected, is it enough to repeat the last `\tacticboard` lie n2000 times?

Comment: the example runs with pdflatex which is usually faster than lualatex, do you need to use luatex?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I have to use LaTeX since I want to have the book in other languages having Unicode characters.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The secnumdepth is a rudiment from other books where it was necessary. And yes, repeat the /tacticboard 2525 times to simulate. I skipped all of them, keeping 4 only. Also, I will have 2525 unique diagrams so caching repeating values will not work here.

Comment: you really have a book with section 5.3.4.5.6.4.3.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.7.6.5.4.3.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.0.8.7.6.5.6.7.8.9.0.9.8.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.0.2.4.5.6.7.1.2.  ?? how on earth is the reader supposed to follow that?

Comment: using pdftex and the code in my answer using pdftex I got 2,367 boards on 233 pages in 3 minutes 11 seconds. using texlive 2024 linux pdftex running in wsl2  on windows

Comment: using the same file with lualatex is 4 minutes 6 seconds, so slower than pdftex but a lot less than 4 hours.

Answer (score 5):

Your `\tacticboard` just makes a `minipage` and `hfill` glue so if as you seem to indicate you have 2000 of these just following each other then your entire document will be set as one paragraph and held in memory till the end, then tex's linebreaker will split them up.

As you know in advance there will be three per line, place a blank line every three lines or test value `\value{diagrams}` and use `\par` if it is a multiple of 3.

```
\documentclass[paper=8.27in:11.69in,DIV=calc,fontsize=12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[includehead, includefoot, inner=0.65in, outer=0.4in, top=0.65in, bottom=0.65in]{geometry}
%\documentclass[headings=openany,paper=165mm:240mm,DIV=calc]{scrbook}
%\usepackage[includehead, includefoot, left=20mm, right=20mm, top=17.5mm, bottom=17.5mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\usepackage{imakeidx}

\titleformat{name=\section, numberless}[display]
  {\LARGE\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\centering{\large}}
\titleformat{\part}[display]
  {\Huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\centering{\thepart}}
\titleformat{name=\part, numberless}[display]
  {\Huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\centering{\Huge}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\Huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\centering{\thechapter . }}
\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}[display]
  {\Huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\centering{\Large}}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%<<
 \markboth{#1}{}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\fancyfoot[LE, RO]{\thepage}

\assignpagestyle{\part}{empty}

\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{texmate}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{55}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{55}

\newcounter{diagrams}

\newcommand\printdiagrams{\footnotesize\refstepcounter{diagrams}\thediagrams}

\setchessboard{labelfontsize=0.5em, showmover=true, moverstyle=triangle, boardfontsize=14pt}
\newcommand\tacticboard[2][]{%
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
            \vfill\strut\scriptsize\vspace{-0.5em}\hspace{2.3em} \printdiagrams \hfill  #1\hspace{1.9em} \vspace{-1em}
            \par\centering\chessboard[#2]\vfill\vspace{2.1em}
    \end{minipage}%
    \ifnum\numexpr(\value{diagrams}/3)*3=\value{diagrams}%
      \par
      \else
      \hfill
    \fi
    \ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\bfseries\rmfamily\Huge\vspace{0.5em}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\rmfamily\Large\vspace{0.25em}}
\renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\bfseries\rmfamily\Huge}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\rmfamily\Large}
\renewcommand\thepart{\Roman{part}. }
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hspace*{\fill}\rmfamily\bfseries\huge Contents\hspace*{\fill}}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}


\part{Positions}
\fancyhead[C]{I. Positions}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.2pt}
\tacticboard[L-0]{setfen=8/8/8/8/8/1K4Q1/7p/6k1 b - - 0 1, moverlift=-1.9ex, movershift=-8.6ex}
\tacticboard[L-0]{setfen=8/8/8/6K1/8/6Q1/5p2/6k1 b - - 0 1, moverlift=-1.9ex, movershift=-8.6ex}
\tacticboard[L-0]{setfen=8/3k1qP1/7K/7P/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1, moverlift=16.6ex, movershift=-8.6ex}
\tacticboard[L-0]{setfen=3q4/1P6/K1k5/P7/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1, moverlift=16.6ex, movershift=-8.6ex}
\tacticboard[L-0]{setfen=3q4/1P6/K1k5/P7/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1, moverlift=16.6ex, movershift=-8.6ex}
\tacticboard[L-0]{setfen=3q4/1P6/K1k5/P7/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1, moverlift=16.6ex, movershift=-8.6ex}
\tacticboard[L-0]{setfen=3q4/1P6/K1k5/P7/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1, moverlift=16.6ex, movershift=-8.6ex}
\tacticboard[L-0]{setfen=3q4/1P6/K1k5/P7/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1, moverlift=16.6ex, movershift=-8.6ex}
\tacticboard[L-0]{setfen=3q4/1P6/K1k5/P7/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1, moverlift=16.6ex, movershift=-8.6ex}
\tacticboard[L-0]{setfen=3q4/1P6/K1k5/P7/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1, moverlift=16.6ex, movershift=-8.6ex}
\tacticboard[L-0]{setfen=3q4/1P6/K1k5/P7/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1, moverlift=16.6ex, movershift=-8.6ex}
\tacticboard[L-0]{setfen=3q4/1P6/K1k5/P7/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1, moverlift=16.6ex, movershift=-8.6ex}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using pdftex and the code in this answer, modified with the last `\tacticboard` repeated so there were 2,367 boards, then using texlive 2024 linux running in wsl2 on windows:

Using pdftex I got 2,367 boards on 233 pages in **3 minutes 11 seconds**.

Using the same file with lualatex is **4 minutes 6 seconds**, so slower than pdftex but a lot less than 4 hours.

Without adding `\par` every three boards, the full document produces no output with pdftex:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].
```

as it can not hold all the boards in memory.

Luatex uses dynamic memory allocation so succeeded but took **6 minutes 12 seconds** so quite a bit slower (and used a lot of memory).

Comment: I'm so slow ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer 233 pages in 3m 11sec isn't so slow:-)

Comment: I should try to get rid of ifthen

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  use linked prop :-)